# SQL Query : Calculating cross distances based on Master detail predefined tables

Tags: sql

I have a database with many tables, especially two tables one store paths and the other one store cities of a path :

Table Paths [ PathID, Name ]
Table Routes [ ID, PathID(Forein Key), City, GoTime, BackTime, GoDistance, BackDistance]

Table Paths :

```
---------------------------------------
|PathID |Name                         |
|-------+-----------------------------|
|1      |NewYork Casablanca Alpha 1   |
|7      |Paris Dubai 6007 10:00       |
---------------------------------------
```

Table Routes :

```
ID     PathID      City       GoTime      BackTime      GoDistance      BackDistance
1      1           NewYork    08:00       23:46         5810            NULL
2      1           Casablanca 15:43       16:03         NULL            5800
3      7           Paris      10:20       14:01         3215            NULL
4      7           Cairo      14:50       09:31         2425            3215
3      7           Dubai      18:21       06:00         NULL            2425
```

I want a Query that gives me all the possible combinations inside the same Path, something like :

```
PathID    CityFrom    CityTo     Distance
```

I don't know if I made myself clear or not but hope you guys could help me, thanx in advance.

This is the good answer done manually !!

```
------------------------------------------------------
|PathID |Go_Back    |CityA      |CityB      |Distance|
|-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------|
|1      |Go         |NewYork    |Casablanca |5810    |
|1      |Back       |Casablanca |NewYork    |5800    |
|7      |Go         |Paris      |Cairo      |3215    |
|7      |Go         |Paris      |Dubai      |5640    |
|7      |Go         |Cairo      |Dubai      |2425    |
|7      |Back       |Dubai      |Cairo      |2425    |
|7      |Back       |Dubai      |Paris      |5640    |
|7      |Back       |Cairo      |Paris      |3215    |
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to two questions.

Q1:
How to split up column "Name"  from table "Paths", so that it is in first normal form. See [wikipedia for a definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). The domain of each attribute contains only atomic values, and the value of each attribute contains only a single value from that domain. You must do this yourself. It might be cumbersome to use the text-processing functions of your database to split up the nonatomic column values. 
Write a script (perl/python/... ) that does this, and re-import the results into a new table.

Q2:
HOw to calculate "possible paths combinations". 
Maybe it is possible with a simple SQL query, by sorting the table. You haven't shown enough data. 
Ultimately, this can be done with recursive SQL. Postgres can do this. It is an advanced topic.
You definitely must decide if your paths can contain loops. (A traveller might decide to take a circular detour many times, although it makes no sense practically. mathematically it is possible, though.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I don't need to put the column "Name" into the first normal form, because it is only for end users that he can easily identify each Path. I think that I didn't make my self clear.
Here is the exact solution of my data: